# issue while installing oracle 12c in linux machine - The installer gui popup window never appears

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I am trying to install Oracle 12c in x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux machine. This is my first time installation. I run the installer from the database folder using `./runInstaller -debug` command. The output is as follows:

```
Starting Oracle Universal Installer...

Checking Temp space: must be greater than 500 MB.   Actual 14103 MB    Passed
Checking swap space: must be greater than 150 MB.   Actual 3964 MB    Passed
Checking monitor: must be configured to display at least 256 colors.    Actual 16777216    Passed
Preparing to launch Oracle Universal Installer from /tmp/OraInstall2015-08-28_09-28-56AM. Please wait ...Archive:  ../stage/Components/oracle.jdk/1.6.0.75.0/1/DataFiles/filegroup3.jar
  inflating: /tmp/OraInstall2015-08-28_09-28-56AM/jdk/lib/ir.idl
  inflating: /tmp/OraInstall2015-08-28_09-28-56AM/jdk/lib/sa-jdi.jar
  ...................

Archive:  ../stage/Components/oracle.jdk/1.6.0.75.0/1/DataFiles/filegroup2.jar  
  .............

Archive:  ../stage/Components/oracle.jdk/1.6.0.75.0/1/DataFiles/filegroup4.jar
  .......

Archive:  ../stage/Components/oracle.jdk/1.6.0.75.0/1/DataFiles/filegroup1.jar  
  ............

Archive:  ../stage/Components/oracle.jdk/1.6.0.75.0/1/DataFiles/filegroup5.jar
  ........  

5 archives were successfully processed.
Archive:  ../stage/Components/oracle.swd.oui/12.1.0.2.0/1/DataFiles/filegroup6.jar
  ...........

Archive:  ../stage/Components/oracle.swd.oui/12.1.0.2.0/1/DataFiles/filegroup2.jar
  ..........

Archive:  ../stage/Components/oracle.swd.oui/12.1.0.2.0/1/DataFiles/filegroup4.jar
  ............

Archive:  ../stage/Components/oracle.swd.oui/12.1.0.2.0/1/DataFiles/filegroup7.jar
  ........

Archive:  ../stage/Components/oracle.swd.oui/12.1.0.2.0/1/DataFiles/filegroup1.jar
  .............

Archive:  ../stage/Components/oracle.swd.oui/12.1.0.2.0/1/DataFiles/filegroup5.jar 
  ....

6 archives were successfully processed.
Archive:  ../stage/Components/oracle.swd.oui.core/12.1.0.2.0/1/DataFiles/filegroup3.jar
  ......


Archive:  ../stage/Components/oracle.swd.oui.core/12.1.0.2.0/1/DataFiles/filegroup2.jar
  ........


Archive:  ../stage/Components/oracle.swd.oui.core/12.1.0.2.0/1/DataFiles/filegroup4.jar
  .........

Archive:  ../stage/Components/oracle.swd.oui.core/12.1.0.2.0/1/DataFiles/filegroup1.jar
  ..........

Archive:  ../stage/Components/oracle.swd.oui.core/12.1.0.2.0/1/DataFiles/filegroup5.jar
  .....

5 archives were successfully processed.
Archive:  ../stage/Components/oracle.swd.oui.core.min/12.1.0.2.0/1/DataFiles/filegroup2.jar
  ....


Archive:  ../stage/Components/oracle.swd.oui.core.min/12.1.0.2.0/1/DataFiles/filegroup1.jar
  ......

2 archives were successfully processed.

LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable :
-------------------------------------------------------
Total args: 26
Command line argument array elements ...
Arg:0:/tmp/OraInstall2015-08-28_09-28-56AM/jdk/jre/bin/java:
Arg:1:-Doracle.installer.library_loc=/tmp/OraInstall2015-08-28_09-28-56AM/oui/lib/linux64:
Arg:2:-Doracle.installer.oui_loc=/tmp/OraInstall2015-08-28_09-28-56AM/oui:
Arg:3:-Doracle.installer.bootstrap=TRUE:
Arg:4:-Doracle.installer.startup_location=/oracle12c/database/install:
Arg:5:-Doracle.installer.jre_loc=/tmp/OraInstall2015-08-28_09-28-56AM/jdk/jre:
Arg:6:-Doracle.installer.nlsEnabled="TRUE":
Arg:7:-Doracle.installer.prereqConfigLoc= :
Arg:8:-Doracle.installer.unixVersion=2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64:
Arg:9:-Doracle.install.setup.workDir=/oracle12c/database:
Arg:10:-DCVU_OS_SETTINGS=SHELL_NOFILE_SOFT_LIMIT:1024,SHELL_UMASK:0022:
Arg:11:-Xms150m:
Arg:12:-Xmx256m:
Arg:13:-XX:MaxPermSize=128M:
Arg:14:-cp:
Arg:15:/tmp/OraInstall2015-08-28_09-28-56AM::/tmp/OraInstall2015-08-28_09-28-56AM/ext/jlib/emca.jar:/tmp/OraInstall2015-08-28_09-28-56AM/ext/jlib/entityManager_proxy.jar:/tmp/OraInstall2015-08-28_09-28-56AM/ext/jlib/prov_fixup.jar:/tmp/OraInstall2015-08-28_09-28-56AM/ext/jlib/orai18n-utility.jar:/tmp/OraInstall2015-08-28_09-28-56AM/ext/jlib/installcommons_1.0.0b.jar:/tmp/OraInstall2015-08-28_09-28-56AM/ext/jlib/wsclient_extended.jar:/tmp/OraInstall2015-08-28_09-28-56AM/ext/jlib/instdb.jar:/tmp/OraInstall2015-08-28_09-28-56AM/ext/jlib/jsch.jar:/tmp/OraInstall2015-08-28_09-28-56AM/ext/jlib/remoteinterfaces.jar:/tmp/OraInstall2015-08-28_09-28-56AM/ext/jlib/OraPrereqChecks.jar:/tmp/OraInstall2015-08-28_09-28-56AM/ext/jlib/orai18n-mapping.jar:/tmp/OraInstall2015-08-28_09-28-56AM/ext/jlib/instcommon.jar:/tmp/OraInstall2015-08-28_09-28-56AM/ext/jlib/emCoreConsole.jar:/tmp/OraInstall2015-08-28_09-28-56AM/ext/jlib/OraPrereq.jar:/tmp/OraInstall2015-08-28_09-28-56AM/ext/jlib/cvu.jar:/tmp/OraInstall2015-08-28_09-28-56AM/ext/jlib/ssh.jar:/tmp/OraInstall2015-08-28_09-28-56AM/ext/jlib/ojdbc6.jar:/tmp/OraInstall2015-08-28_09-28-56AM/ext/jlib/adf-share-ca.jar:/tmp/OraInstall2015-08-28_09-28-56AM/ext/jlib/jmxspi.jar:/tmp/OraInstall2015-08-28_09-28-56AM/ext/jlib/javax.security.jacc_1.0.0.0_1-1.jar:/tmp/OraInstall2015-08-28_09-28-56AM/oui/jlib/OraInstaller.jar:/tmp/OraInstall2015-08-28_09-28-56AM/oui/jlib/oneclick.jar:/tmp/OraInstall2015-08-28_09-28-56AM/oui/jlib/xmlparserv2.jar:/tmp/OraInstall2015-08-28_09-28-56AM/oui/jlib/share.jar:/tmp/OraInstall2015-08-28_09-28-56AM/oui/jlib/OraInstallerNet.jar:/tmp/OraInstall2015-08-28_09-28-56AM/oui/jlib/emCfg.jar:/tmp/OraInstall2015-08-28_09-28-56AM/oui/jlib/emocmutl.jar:/tmp/OraInstall2015-08-28_09-28-56AM/oui/jlib/OraPrereq.jar:/tmp/OraInstall2015-08-28_09-28-56AM/oui/jlib/jsch.jar:/tmp/OraInstall2015-08-28_09-28-56AM/oui/jlib/ssh.jar:/tmp/OraInstall2015-08-28_09-28-56AM/oui/jlib/remoteinterfaces.jar:/tmp/OraInstall2015-08-28_09-28-56AM/oui/jlib/http_client.jar:/tmp/OraInstall2015-08-28_09-28-56AM/oui/jlib/OraSuiteInstaller.jar:../stage/Components/oracle.swd.opatch/12.1.0.2.0/1/DataFiles/jlib/opatch.jar:../stage/Components/oracle.swd.opatch/12.1.0.2.0/1/DataFiles/jlib/opatchactions.jar:../stage/Components/oracle.swd.opatch/12.1.0.2.0/1/DataFiles/jlib/opatchprereq.jar:../stage/Components/oracle.swd.opatch/12.1.0.2.0/1/DataFiles/jlib/opatchutil.jar:/tmp/OraInstall2015-08-28_09-28-56AM/oui/jlib/OraCheckPoint.jar:/tmp/OraInstall2015-08-28_09-28-56AM/oui/jlib/InstImages.jar:/tmp/OraInstall2015-08-28_09-28-56AM/oui/jlib/InstHelp.jar:/tmp/OraInstall2015-08-28_09-28-56AM/oui/jlib/InstHelp_de.jar:/tmp/OraInstall2015-08-28_09-28-56AM/oui/jlib/InstHelp_es.jar:/tmp/OraInstall2015-08-28_09-28-56AM/oui/jlib/InstHelp_fr.jar:/tmp/OraInstall2015-08-28_09-28-56AM/oui/jlib/InstHelp_it.jar:/tmp/OraInstall2015-08-28_09-28-56AM/oui/jlib/InstHelp_ja.jar:/tmp/OraInstall2015-08-28_09-28-56AM/oui/jlib/InstHelp_ko.jar:/tmp/OraInstall2015-08-28_09-28-56AM/oui/jlib/InstHelp_pt_BR.jar:/tmp/OraInstall2015-08-28_09-28-56AM/oui/jlib/InstHelp_zh_CN.jar:/tmp/OraInstall2015-08-28_09-28-56AM/oui/jlib/InstHelp_zh_TW.jar:/tmp/OraInstall2015-08-28_09-28-56AM/oui/jlib/oracle_ice.jar:/tmp/OraInstall2015-08-28_09-28-56AM/oui/jlib/help-share.jar:/tmp/OraInstall2015-08-28_09-28-56AM/oui/jlib/ohj.jar:/tmp/OraInstall2015-08-28_09-28-56AM/oui/jlib/ewt3.jar:/tmp/OraInstall2015-08-28_09-28-56AM/oui/jlib/ewt3-swingaccess.jar:/tmp/OraInstall2015-08-28_09-28-56AM/oui/jlib/swingaccess.jar::/tmp/OraInstall2015-08-28_09-28-56AM/oui/jlib/jewt4.jar:/tmp/OraInstall2015-08-28_09-28-56AM/oui/jlib/orai18n-collation.jar:/tmp/OraInstall2015-08-28_09-28-56AM/oui/jlib/orai18n-mapping.jar:/tmp/OraInstall2015-08-28_09-28-56AM/oui/jlib/ojmisc.jar:/tmp/OraInstall2015-08-28_09-28-56AM/oui/jlib/xml.jar:/tmp/OraInstall2015-08-28_09-28-56AM/oui/jlib/srvm.jar:/tmp/OraInstall2015-08-28_09-28-56AM/oui/jlib/srvmasm.jar:
Arg:16:oracle.install.ivw.db.driver.DBInstaller:
Arg:17:-scratchPath:
Arg:18:/tmp/OraInstall2015-08-28_09-28-56AM:
Arg:19:-sourceLoc:
Arg:20:/oracle12c/database/install/../stage/products.xml:
Arg:21:-sourceType:
Arg:22:network:
Arg:23:-timestamp:
Arg:24:2015-08-28_09-28-56AM:
Arg:25:-debug:
-------------------------------------------------------
Initializing Java Virtual Machine from /tmp/OraInstall2015-08-28_09-28-56AM/jdk/jre/bin/java. Please wait...
[oracle@korbsbvmlx22 database]$ [main] [ 2015-08-28 09:29:05.048 IST ] [ClusterVerification.getInstance:426]  Method Entry. workDir=/tmp frameworkHome=/oracle12c/database/install/../stage/cvu
[main] [ 2015-08-28 09:29:05.062 IST ] [ParamManager.<init>:668]  m_paramInstantiated set to TRUE
[main] [ 2015-08-28 09:29:05.062 IST ] [VerificationUtil.getLocalHost:1312]  Hostname retrieved: korbsbvmlx22, returned: korbsbvmlx22
[main] [ 2015-08-28 09:29:05.064 IST ] [VerificationUtil.getDestLoc:3712]  ==== CV_DESTLOC(pre-fetched value): '/tmp/'
[main] [ 2015-08-28 09:29:05.065 IST ] [VerificationUtil.getExecutionEnvironment:7586]  RDBMS Version is -->12.1.0.2.0
[main] [ 2015-08-28 09:29:05.065 IST ] [VerificationUtil.validateCmdLineExecEnvironment:7602]  Entered validateCmdLineExecEnvironment
[main] [ 2015-08-28 09:29:05.105 IST ] [Version.isPre:610]  version to be checked 12.1.0.2.0 major version to check against 10
[main] [ 2015-08-28 09:29:05.105 IST ] [Version.isPre:621]  isPre.java: Returning FALSE
[main] [ 2015-08-28 09:29:05.106 IST ] [Version.isPre:610]  version to be checked 12.1.0.2.0 major version to check against 10
[main] [ 2015-08-28 09:29:05.106 IST ] [Version.isPre:621]  isPre.java: Returning FALSE
[main] [ 2015-08-28 09:29:05.107 IST ] [Version.isPre:610]  version to be checked 12.1.0.2.0 major version to check against 11
[main] [ 2015-08-28 09:29:05.107 IST ] [Version.isPre:621]  isPre.java: Returning FALSE
[main] [ 2015-08-28 09:29:05.107 IST ] [Version.isPre:642]  version to be checked 12.1.0.2.0 major version to check against 11 minor version to check against 2
[main] [ 2015-08-28 09:29:05.108 IST ] [Version.isPre:651]  isPre: Returning FALSE for major version check
[main] [ 2015-08-28 09:29:05.108 IST ] [UnixSystem.isHAConfigured:2788]  olrFileName = /etc/oracle/olr.loc
[main] [ 2015-08-28 09:29:05.109 IST ] [VerificationUtil.isHAConfigured:4181]  haConfigured=false
[main] [ 2015-08-28 09:29:05.109 IST ] [VerificationUtil.validateCmdLineExecEnvironment:7639]  Exit validateCmdLineExecEnvironment
[main] [ 2015-08-28 09:29:05.116 IST ] [ConfigUtil.importConfig:97]  ==== CVU config file: /oracle12c/database/install/../stage/cvu//cv/admin/cvu_config
[main] [ 2015-08-28 09:29:05.117 IST ] [ConfigUtil.importConfig:114]  ==== Picked up config variable: cv_raw_check_enabled : TRUE
[main] [ 2015-08-28 09:29:05.118 IST ] [ConfigUtil.importConfig:114]  ==== Picked up config variable: cv_sudo_binary_location : /usr/local/bin/sudo
[main] [ 2015-08-28 09:29:05.118 IST ] [ConfigUtil.importConfig:114]  ==== Picked up config variable: cv_pbrun_binary_location : /usr/local/bin/pbrun
[main] [ 2015-08-28 09:29:05.119 IST ] [ConfigUtil.importConfig:114]  ==== Picked up config variable: cv_assume_cl_version : 12.1
[main] [ 2015-08-28 09:29:05.119 IST ] [ConfigUtil.isDefined:200]  ==== Is ORACLE_SRVM_REMOTESHELL defined? : false
[main] [ 2015-08-28 09:29:05.121 IST ] [Library.load:194]  library.load
[main] [ 2015-08-28 09:29:05.122 IST ] [sPlatform.isHybrid:66]  osName=Linux osArch=amd64 JVM=64 rc=false
[main] [ 2015-08-28 09:29:05.122 IST ] [Library.load:262]  Property oracle.installer.library_loc is set to value=/tmp/OraInstall2015-08-28_09-28-56AM/oui/lib/linux64
[main] [ 2015-08-28 09:29:05.123 IST ] [Library.load:264]  Loading  library /tmp/OraInstall2015-08-28_09-28-56AM/oui/lib/linux64/libsrvm12.so
[main] [ 2015-08-28 09:29:05.124 IST ] [ConfigUtil.getConfiguredValue:182]  ==== Fallback to env var 'ORACLE_SRVM_REMOTESHELL'=null
[main] [ 2015-08-28 09:29:05.125 IST ] [ConfigUtil.isDefined:200]  ==== Is ORACLE_SRVM_REMOTECOPY defined? : false
[main] [ 2015-08-28 09:29:05.125 IST ] [ConfigUtil.getConfiguredValue:182]  ==== Fallback to env var 'ORACLE_SRVM_REMOTECOPY'=null
```

As seen in debug messages after "Please wait..." no installer window opens and there are further messages that is displayed in the console and then it is always like that. I have verified the logs in `/tmp` directory and it appears to be clean. I am stuck with this issue since long and do not know how to proceed.

Please guide.

Comment: Are you running the installer on your local machine or on a remote machine? Which user are you using to run the installer? When you start `xterm` instead of `./runInstaller -debug`, does the xterm open?

Comment: I am running the installer on a remote machine. No xterm does not work. I get the error "-bash: xterm: command not found". May be i should update the path.

Comment: Hi Andreas, xterm was not installed in the machine. I used yum to install the same. I am using putty to get to the remote vm and the I hit the command xterm. It hangs. Please advise.

Comment: I also tried xclock command, I get the output "Warning: Missing charsets in String to FontSet conversion" and then it is stuck.

Comment: If you are doing ssh can you try with `ssh -X <host>` option?

Comment: Do you have an X server such as Xming installed on your local machine? The first thing you need to ensure is that X11 applications like xterm are working. Please check [How to use X11 forwarding with PuTTY](http://superuser.com/questions/119792/how-to-use-x11-forwarding-with-putty). Alternatively you can use [VNC](http://linuxconfig.org/configuring-vnc-server-access-on-a-redhat-linux) to access the remote machine.

Comment: Hi Andreas, I have enabled X11 forwarding with Putty:- cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config | grep X gives O/p - AcceptEnv XMODIFIERS
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
X11UseLocalhost yes  Still xterm does not work.

Comment: I have set display as DISPLAY=:0.0 export DISPLAY as root user. Then I switch to oracle user and do echo $DISPLAY which gives me O/P :0.0. Then I try xterm which does not open xterm window :(.

Comment: I tried with X11 forwarding with Putty which didn't work so I instead swicthed to vnc server. In my server where I wish to install oracle I started the vnc server and from my local windows machine I connected to vnc server using vnc viewer, Later tried to run the oracle installer but no luck there. Then tried xterm but this too did not open new window. I really do not know where I am going wrong.

Comment: Ok so now I could resolve the issue successfully. As Andreas pointed out I had to ensure atleast xterm command opens up a new window. With putty even after X11 forwarding I was unable to achieve this. I then installed VNC server in the server where I had to install oracle. I connected to the sever from my local machine (windows) using vnc viewer. I used the vnc server ip to connect. After I logged in to the server using viewer I had to set display and then run xterm. All worked well then.